# If $G$ is $LL(k)$, then $L(G)$ is a deterministic context free language.

Tags: automata, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

In formal language theory, a context-free language (CFL) is a language generated by some context-free grammar (CFG).

For every grammar, If the correct production can be deduced from the
partially constructed tree and the next $k$ symbols in
the unscanned string, for every possible step, then
the grammar is said to be $LL(k)$.

Prove that : If $G$ is $LL(k)$, then $L(G)$ is a deterministic context free language.

Comment: Both $LL(k)$ and DCFL can not be inherently ambiguous grammar

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay Please write an answer ... and please write more details... i'm new to LL(k) grammars

Comment: Read @https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_grammar

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay Actually, I do not think that unambiguity of both types of languages is of much use here (there are unambiguous languages, which are not deterministic context free). Instead, I would recommend the OP to think of "implementing" an LL-parser on a deterministic pushdown automaton...